# Sum of a variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not experienced on VBA and I wanna develop a summarization of the Column A in column B by blocking the last column, eg.:

```
B3 = A3:$A$10 
B4 = A4:$A$10
```

---

```
A     B
10    55
9     45
8     36
7     28
6     21
5     15
4     10
3     6
2     3
1     1
```

I was trying to use a loop (for) but I didn't manage to (see line before end if)

```
For age = 1 To Table_lastRow
            If age < 4 Then
                Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = ""
            ElseIf age = 4 Then
                Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = "Nx"
            ElseIf age >= 5 Then
                Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("X5:X" & Table_lastRow))
            End If
        Next age
```

Comment: Do you need VBA, can do a running sum with equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range("a1", "a100")  is equal with range("a1:a100")

you can use below two method.

```
Range("X" & age, "X" & Table_lastRow)
```

or

```
Range ("X" & age & ":X" & Table_lastRow)
```

### entire code

```
    For age = 1 To Table_lastRow
        If age < 4 Then
            Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = ""
        ElseIf age = 4 Then
            Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = "Nx"
        ElseIf age >= 5 Then
            Table.Cells(age, 25).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("X" & age, "X" & Table_lastRow))
        End If
    Next age
```

Comment: No need to do string math like `"X" & age`. Excel has functions like `.Cells()`, `.Offset()` and `.Resize()` to do all that without having the nightmare of maintaining references to the `X` column and `Y` row all the time. They all operate _relative_ to one `Range` address that is far easier to maintain and less error-prone.

Comment: @Dy.Lee I was using your code for the formula and it seems to be ok. But once in a while it do not calculate the formula for and the result is 0 of each row. do you have an idea why? thanks

Comment: @Alin-IustinianToderita,I guess I need to know the address of your data. The starting point of the loop is questionable.

Comment: @Dy.Lee can I provide you the file?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `.Resize()` function to expand a cell into a table.

This code will produces the desired result:

```
Public Sub RunningSum()

    ' Define input and output ranges
    Dim r_A As Range, r_B As Range
    Set r_A = [D7]
    Set r_B = [E7]

    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    ' Find how many rows are filled
    If IsEmpty(r_A) Then
        n = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r_A.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        n = 1
    Else
        n = Range(r_A, r_A.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If

    ' Loop to fill "B" values
    For i = 1 To n
        r_B.Cells(i, 1).Value2 = _
            WorksheetFunction.Sum(r_A.Cells(i, 1).Resize(n - i + 1, 1))
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: scr]